# WPFs DrawingContext.DrawText doesn't draw

Tags: wpf, text, drawing, controls, render

I a writing a ruler control and I want to draw a scale beneath it. Unfortunately WPFs DrawingContext.DrawText method (although it gets invoked) doesn't draw anything. Did anybody have the same problem and knows a solution? This is the part of the code where the text gets rendered:

```
protected void RenderRulerScale(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    int value = 0;
    for (double x =  this.LargeUnit * (this.ActualWidth / this.Maximum);
        x < this.ActualWidth; x += this.LargeUnit * (this.ActualWidth / this.Maximum))
    {
        string unitString = (++value).ToString() + this.UnitName;
        FormattedText formattedUnitString = new FormattedText(unitString,
            new CultureInfo("en-US"), FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface("Arial"), 5.0, Brushes.Black)
            {
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                MaxTextWidth = 2 * this.LargeUnit,
                MaxTextHeight = 25.0
            };
        drawingContext.DrawText(formattedUnitString, new Point(x, (2.0 / 3.0) *
            this.ActualHeight));
    }
}
```

This method is called in the OnRender method:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    this.RenderRulerScale(drawingContext);
}
```

Comment: Do you get other things (e.g. lines) drawn by that DrawingContext?

Comment: Nothing at all! Not even a pixel :-(

Comment: So where does the DrawingContext come from and where and when is your drawing code supposed to execute? Post more code please.

Comment: I found a little bug. x started with this.LargeUnit, but it should have been this.LargeUnit * (this.ActualWidth / this.Maximum)! this.LargeUnit is in my case 1024 (1GB). But this didn't fix the problem. I stepped through the for loop and checked the x values and they are definitly correct.

Comment: If you draw a short line instead of the ruler text, do you see that? Just to make sure your drawing works at all. Maybe something else is simply drawn over your drawing.

Comment: I added this line to the code:

Comment: drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 1.0), new Point(0.0, (2.0 / 3.0) * this.ActualHeight), new Point(this.ActualWidth, (2.0 / 3.0) * this.ActualHeight));

Comment: And it worked, so I guess there is no problem with the drawing context

Comment: Ok, no problem with the DrawingContext. But, although you said you checked the x-Values, why not draw the test line from x to x+10 or so, instead of 0 to ActualWidth. And i think 5.0 is a very small font size.

Comment: I just drew line instead of text (one line for each text at the same position) and they rendered perfectly. I also changes the font size to 10.0, but it is still not rendered.

Comment: I found a solution: The problem was the text alignment. I set it back to left and it just worked. I don't know what the problem was, maybe it is a bug in the WPFs implementation. Thank you very much, for your help and assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution! I think the problem was the text alignment. I set it back to left and it just worked. Here is the code:

```
int value = 0;
for (double x = this.LargeUnit * (this.ActualWidth / this.Maximum);
    x < this.ActualWidth; x += this.LargeUnit * (this.ActualWidth / this.Maximum))
{
    string unitString = (++value).ToString() + this.UnitName;
    FormattedText formattedUnitString = new FormattedText(unitString,
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(new FontFamily("Arial"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal,
        FontStretches.Normal) , 10.0, Brushes.Black);
    drawingContext.DrawText(formattedUnitString,
        new Point(x - (formattedUnitString.Width / 2.0), (2.0 / 3.0) *
        this.ActualHeight));
}
```

Comment: [`MaxTextWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.maxtextwidth.aspx)
has an effect on `origin`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856575/5198722).