# WPF word alignment issues while MaxTextWidth is set

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using FormattedText to display text. I need to align the text horizontally as per options provided. Everything works fine till I set the "MaxTextWidth" property(I need this for word trimming). How do I align the text along with word trimming enabled?

```
    FormattedText formatted_text = new FormattedText(
            text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            typeface, em_size, brush);
   formatted_text.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
   drawingContext.DrawText(formatted_text, origin);
```

This works fine aligning the code as expected. But I need to trim the word w.r.t MaxTextWidth. I run into issues in setting MaxTextWidth. How do I calculate MaxTextWidth?

The point in the image is the origin.

This is what I get when I dont set MaxTextWidth

[image]

[image]

This when I set MaxTextWidth = 100

How do I calculate MaxTextWidth so I can align the trimmed sentence?

Edit: Adding more screenshots
[image: Before setting MaxTextWidth, properly aligned]

Before setting MaxTextWidth, properly aligned,
After setting

[image]
I lose the word alignment, look w.r.t the reference point shown

Comment: It is a strange behavior that `MaxTextWidth` is added to X-coordinate of the origin. Do you want to calculate the width of the longest word?

Comment: Will setting the MaxTextWidth  to the width of the longest word solve the issue here?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what issue you want to solve. Could you edit your question and describe the desired alignment exactly?

Comment: I am aligning the word to right (for understanding am using a point for reference here), so ideally my trimmed text should have been aligned as in image1, but is not the case. Setting MaxTextWidth shifts my texts from the reference point.

Comment: See the last paragraph in the image of my answer. What you have is the red dot. And you're looking for the blue dot, aren't you? Then you need `correctionX` at the end of my code example.

Answer (score 3):

It is a strange behavior of
[`DrawingContext.DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawtext.aspx)
that [`MaxTextWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.maxtextwidth.aspx)
has an effect on `origin`.
If `FormattedText` is right aligned and `MaxTextWidth = 0`, i.e. default, `DrawText` puts the
text left of origin. If `MaxTextWidth > 0`, `DrawText` puts the text right of origin.

Hence you have to substract `MaxTextWidth` from `origin.X` if right aligned
and the half if centered. Here is an example. Blue dots are the desired origins and red ones the corrected.
[image: DrawText origin example]

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

public void DrawTextTest(DrawingContext dc) {
    var y = 100.0;
    foreach (var align in new TextAlignment[]{
        TextAlignment.Left, TextAlignment.Center, TextAlignment.Right}) {
        foreach (var width in new double[] { 0.0, 150.0 }) {
            DrawText(dc, new Point(400, y), align, width);
            y += 25.0;
        }
        y += 45.0;
    }
}

private void DrawText(DrawingContext dc, Point origin,
    TextAlignment align, double maxTextWidth) {
    var f = new FormattedText(
        "This is a text with TextAlignment = " + align.ToString()
            + " and MaxTextWidth = " + maxTextWidth.ToString() + ".",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface("Arial"), 12.0, Brushes.Black
    ) {
        TextAlignment = align,
        MaxTextWidth = maxTextWidth
    };

    dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Blue, null, origin, 1.0, 1.0);
    var correctionX = -maxTextWidth * (align == TextAlignment.Right ? 1.0
        : (align == TextAlignment.Center ? 0.5 : 0.0));
    origin.Offset(correctionX, 0.0);
    dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Red, null, origin, 1.0, 1.0);
    dc.DrawText(f, origin);
}
```

Comment: Dude, your answer solved my problem, thanks a lot! In short this was all I needed: **you have to substract MaxTextWidth from origin.X if right aligned and the half if centered**.

Comment: how can fix justify alignment in RTL text !?

Comment: @Behzed, I've never dealed with RTL text. You can changed the `FlowDirection`argument in code above and see, whether it makes a difference.